# First element in a double pointer to struct is jiberrish

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

I am creating a simple array of structures in C, but the first structure is always jibberish. How do i fix this?

I have tried to set the first element of the double pointer to struct in many ways but it always fails.

This is my graph.h file:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include "set.h"

typedef struct urlNode * URLList;
typedef struct GraphRep * Graph;

struct urlNode {
    int id;
    char* URL_NAME;
    URLList       next; // link to next node
};

struct GraphRep {
    int nV;
    URLList * collections;
};

Graph newGraph(Set s);
int nameToId(Graph g, char *name);
void showGraph(Graph g);

#endif
```

And my newGraph(Set s) function looks like this:

```
Graph newGraph(Set s){

    int size = nElems(s);
    Graph new_graph = malloc(sizeof(struct GraphRep));
    if (new_graph == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: COULDNT ALLOCATE GRAPH\n");
    }

    new_graph->nV = size;
    char *name = getNextVal(s);


    // THIS IS THE NODE TO BE ADDED TO THE GRAPH
    URLList list_to_add = malloc(sizeof(struct urlNode));
    list_to_add->URL_NAME = strdup(name);
    list_to_add->id = 0;
    list_to_add->next = NULL;


    // HERE I ADD THE NODE TO THE GRAPH.
    new_graph->collections[0] = list_to_add;

    // PRINT OUT THE VALUES OF THE NEWLY ADDED NODE TO MAKE SURE IT WORKS
    // THE URL_NAME IS PRINTED OUT FINE 
    // BUT THE ID IS JIBBERISH.
    printf("%s\n", new_graph->collections[0]->URL_NAME);
    printf("%d\n", new_graph->collections[0]->id);
    if(new_graph->collections[0]->next != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", new_graph->collections[0]->next->URL_NAME);
        printf("%d\n", new_graph->collections[0]->next->id);            
    }
    printf("\n");

    return new_graph;
}
```

I expect new_graph->collections[0]->id to be 0 but it keeps on giving me random ints.
Also even if the next for the newly declared pointer to struct is NULL, it still gives me a jibberish next value too.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @Emalp The pointer  collections is not initialized.

Comment: You are setting new_graph->collection[0]->id to a pointer (list_to_add) which is probably not what you want.  I'm not clear what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you want to set it to list_to_add->id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data member `collections` of the object `*new_graph` is not initialized.

There is initialized only this data member

```
new_graph->nV = size;
```

So this statement

```
new_graph->collections[0] = list_to_add;
```

results in undefined behavior.

If you need an array of pointers of the type `URLList` you have to allocate the memory and its address assign to the pointer `collections`.

For example

```
new_graph->collections = malloc( new_graph->nV * sizeof( URLList ) );
```

And after that this statement

```
new_graph->collections[0] = list_to_add;
```

could be valid.

(I suppose that the data member `nV` corresponds to the number of elements in the dynamically allocated array though it may not be truth)

Pay attention to that as the string pointed to by the pointer `name` is not changed in the function then it is better to declare it like

```
const char *name = getNextVal(s);
```

Comment: how would you say I'd initialise this? The new_graph->collections is a dynamic array, that's why its a double pointer to the original struct. Only the first index 0 gives jibberish id, if I were to add more elements as new_graph->collections[1] = another_list_to_add then it works.

Comment: @Emalp Where is it the dynamic array? Where is memory allocated for the array?